Properties of $\mathcal{O}$-modules on a ringed site and on a ringed topos
I have a question on terminology around being intrinsic properties in the stacks project.
First, a ringed topos and an module on it seem to be defined by specifying a site.
In fact, in 01D3, it seems that a ringed topos requires a site where the structural sheaf of rings is defined.
Also, a module on a ringed topos is defined as a (good) sheaf on the site where the topos underlies.
However, there appear several explanations where we cannot fix a site underlying a given ringed topos in the text.
For example, at the first paragraph in 03DK, it explains "we first define the local types for sheaves of modules on a ringed site, and then we immediately show that these types are intrinsic, hence make sense for sheaves of modules on ringed topoi".
Moreover, just after the proof of 03DM in 03DK, it says "Hence from now on we may refer to the properties of O-modules defined in Definition 18.23.1 without specifying a site".
Thus, I wonder the authors implicitly regard a ringed topos and a module on it as site-free notions, but I feel some gaps between the original definitions and this perspective.
I would appreciate it if you could tell me any clarification, references, or point out where I am misunderstanding.
Thank you for your cooperation.

Hi there! Can you please add the tag links to the stacks project? This makes it easier to follow your question.

Dear Martin, thank you for your advice! I added the tag links. Some sentences cannot be linked directly, but I hope the fix works.

From what I see there, it looks like maybe they're saying that the properties are invariant within a "geometric equivalence" class of sites, so you can forget about the exact site used and focus on the geometric equivalence class instead.  Just a guess, though...

Dear Daniel, thank you for sharing your thoughts. As you said, they might just explain properties of modules which are preserved under geometric equivalences, and the definition of a ringed topos and a module on it would require one exact site. I appreciate your cooperation on this soft question.

A ringed topos is just a topos together with a ring object in the topos. The definition of ring object is valid in any category with finite products; it does not depend on any more sophisticated properties of the topos and certainly doesn’t depend on a site. More precisely, there is an obvious isomorphism between the category of ring objects in a sheaf topos and the category of sheaves of rings, as they are usually defined. The same thing holds with groups, monoids, etc.; we only require a purely equational theory where the operators take as input finitely many things (aka a finite product theory).
Similarly, the theory of a ring together with a module over that ring is also expressible purely in terms of finite products. Thus, given a ring object in a category with finite products, one may discuss a module object over that ring object; a sheaf of modules is such a module object. Again, this depends only on the property of having finite products, not on anything more sophisticated.
For fancier notions, like a locally ringed topos, you will need more than just finite products in your definition. However, toposes have a powerful tool known as the “internal logic” than can be used to define such things. The internal logic is defined using properties of the topos as a category, not in terms of any site; it is therefore invariant under equivalence of categories, meaning the internal logic is site-independent.
